# solidity - allowance delegation - what if the owner spent it already

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

So userA delegates his tokens to be spent by me to whoever I want. That's great.
let's say userA's balance was 200Token. and he delegated 150 Token to me..
Now, userA can still transfer 180Token to some other account. So after that userA has 20Token remaining.
Now,  i come in and want to use the delegated tokens that userA gave me, but it turns out I won't be able too.

So what happened is he first gave me a permission to spend ,  but then he spent those, so I can't spend them anymore.

Is this how it works and how it should be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. An address can only use up to the approved amount or actual balance. If you were approved for 150 and the balance is 20 you can only retrieve 20. The remaining 130 would be available if additional tokens are deposited in the future.